# TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable

Tags: python

I currently struggle to understand why the following code is not working:

```
import json
import random

def _time_series_prc(start_date, count, periodicity, is_history=True):
    values = []

    print(type(start_date))
    print(type(periodicity))

    for i in range(count - 1):
        value = random.uniform(0, 1)
        values.append(value)

    return _build_series(values, start_date, periodicity, is_history)


def _build_series(values, start_date, periodicity, is_history):
    if is_history:
        values.reverse()

    return {
        'periodicity': periodicity,
        'startDate': start_date,
        'values': values,
    }

result = _time_series_prc('2019-07-17', 52, 'WEEKLY')

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4));
```

output:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

At line 7, the `json.dumps` I get the error: TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable`. Im not using ptyhon very long But I cant understand how this can be a function pointer instead of the returned value.

Comment: We need to see `start_date ` and `periodicity `... and their types: `print(type(start_date))` and `print(type(periodicity))`. You could be failing to call a function like: `periodicity()` or `start_date()`. If you are actually trying to serialize a function for later use, consider `pickle` instead of `json`

Comment: something in your return value from build_series is a function. possibly periodicity.

Comment: added the prints for the types. they are both string

Comment: @Mulgard Your code works for me

Comment: @Mulgard Can you try running your code again

Comment: @Mulgard What's your version?

Comment: Its python 3.7. But im seriously getting that error Oo

Comment: The code runs for me in 3.7.1 without any issues

Comment: Also runs fine on 2.7.16 and 3.7.3 for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me on Python 3.7.3.

Also note that `for i in range(count - 1):` is going to give you 51 results instead of 52 in this case (`print(len(result['values']))`). Also try removing the `;` in your last line of code just in case :)

Comment: `;`s rock.......